# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: at on.Exercise.main(Exercise.java:3)

Tags: java

I get Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: at on.Exercise.main(Exercise.java:3) and this is my code

[image]

```
import java.util.*;
public class Exercise {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      Integer nums[] = new Integer[]{1, 4, 17, 7, 25, 3, 100};
      int sum = 0;
      System.out.println("Original Array: ");
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nums));
      for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {      
          sum = sum + nums[i];
      }
      double average = sum / nums.length;
      System.out.println("The average of the said array is: " + average);
      System.out.println("The numbers in the said array that are greater than the average are: ");
      for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
          if(nums[i] > average) {
              System.out.println(nums[i]);
          }
      }
   }
}
```

idk how to solve it

Comment: You should wrap your code in back ticks, so we can analyze here

Comment: the code is correct, i think the problem is related to the program that you are executing java files with.Try to write a simple code("hello world") and i think the problem will remain the same .

Comment: You miss the package declaration?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no package statement.  The compiler believes you are in the package "on", meaning the class file for Exercise.java is in a folder named "on" and you are compiling it from the root of "on".  But the source code has no package statement at the top that would look like:

package on;